# How to create dash table from nested dictionary?

Tags: plotly-dash

I have the following dictionary:

```
nested_dict = {
    'Type A':   {'Type A':  10, 'Type B': 20},
    'Type EE':  {'Type B':  40, 'Type C': 50, 'Type A': 60},
    'Type FFF': {'Type ZZ': 70, 'Type FFF': 80, 'Type A': 90, 'Type AA': 1}
}
```

I want to create dash table as follows:

```
|--------------------------------|
|    class  |      predictions   |
|           |--------------------|
|           |  TYPE    | COUTER  |
|--------------------------------|
|           | Type A   |  10     | 
| Type A    | Type B   |  20     |
|--------------------------------|
|           | Type B   |  40     |
| Type EE   | Type C   |  50     |
|           | Type A   |  60     |
|--------------------------------|
|           | Type zz  |  70     |
| Type FFF  | Type FFF |  80     |
|           | Type A   |  90     |
|           | Type AA  |  1      |
|--------------------------------|
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642786/multilevel-dataframe-to-dash-table should be helpful to you in figuring out how to convert the dataframe into a dash table with multi-level indexes